# retrieve single record with kohana 3.3 with request->param() is NULL

Tags: database, request, kohana, record

i try to use kohana framework but i have a little issue wen i try to retrieve a single record from table of my database.
my table:

```
ads
 id_ads
 title_ads
 description_ads
```

my controller:

```
public function action_single()
{
    $ads_id = $this->request->param('id_ads');
    $ads = ORM::factory('ads', $ads_id);

    $view = new View('ads/single');  // load the view/ads/single.php
    $view->set('ads', $ads);        // set 'ads' object to view

    $this->template->set('content', $view);
}
```

my view

```
<h2><?php echo $ads->title_ads; ?></h2>
<pre><?php echo $ads->description_ads; ?></pre>
```

when i go to to *localhost/kohana/index.php/ads/single/1* the browser display nothing, where is the problem?

Comment: I assume proper routing has been set? Do you see the HTML and it just isn't fill with the expected values? Did you check the error log?

Comment: my route setting is

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
 ->defaults(array(
  'controller' => 'ads',
  'action'     => 'index',
 ));

html say me nothing, errors log too...

Comment: Sorry but this is too little information to diagnose the problem. A starting point might be that you request `id_ads` but set it as `id` in the controller. However, this does not explain a blank site. Please make sure error reporting is enabled and everything except receiving the record works as expected.

Comment: how can i enabled it? im new to kohana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$ads_id = $this->request->param('id_ads');
$ads =ORM::factory('ads'->find($ads_id);
```

or

```
$ads_id = $this->request->param('id_ads');
$ads =ORM::factory('ads')->where("id","=",$ads_id)->find();
```

to pass parameters, i think, is better (easier) to extend Controller_Template
in this way:

```
class Controller_News extends Controller_Template{
...
   public function action_single()
   {
     ...
     $view->ads=$ads;
     $this->template->content = $view;
   }
}
```